# The location of the compiled binaries of matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

What is the location of the compiled binaries of matplotlib after I use `pip install matplotlib` to install it?

Answer (score 0):

Generally it is located in the first path in `$PYTHONPATH`, if this variable is set. If it is not set, it is located in `path/to/current/python/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

You can specify other install location via `--root`, `--target` or `--user` pip option. When using --user option, you should have set `PYTHONUSERBASE` system variable before.

If you are using system version of pip and python (installed through system packaging manager), then search in system paths. For Debian it is `/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages`.

There are no binaries like 'matplotlib', only library files are present.